# Is it appropriate to ask questions that ask for help in understanding how open source project code is organized?

Tags: discussion, questions

A few minutes after posting [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139696/which-files-under-numpy-core-src-multiarray-implement-the-core-functionality-ne), I began to wonder if its even appropriate as perhaps the answer is subjective? I'd rather delete my own question, than have it closed from under me. Are questions that ask for help in "source-diving" appropriate for SO?

If yes, what's the right tag for such types of questions?

Comment: Related Area51 proposal: [Code understanding](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65174/code-understanding?referrer=E9UyPC567iiP4kswouKlsg2)

Comment: Your question as it currently stand is way too broad for on SO. Which is also noticeable by the fact that you ask several question (if which some or subjective) . So both the `too broad` and the `primarily opinion-based` close vote reasons could apply here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In general, it's very hard to make these sorts of questions on topic.  It all depends on the scope of your question.

If you're asking about an entire project? Probably too broad.
If you're asking about one thing in one project? Could be too broad, depending on the following:

- Are you asking about one logical piece (e.g., something that could be shown as one particular design pattern?) (If not, probably too broad)
- Are you asking multiple questions? (Too broad)
- Are you asking the question in such a way as to invite opinion? (Is X correct?)  For any definition of 'correct', you have to provide your strict criteria for what correct means. Correct could mean "Works for me", and correct could mean, "Scales at 1M requests/day." or it could mean "Scales at 1000 concurrent requests on this type of system".
- What's your end goal? Is it to learn something about the framework? Or to solve a specific problem. If it's the former, it's extremely likely you'll invite opinion or a really broad answer. If it's the latter, you should be OK (just tell us the problem and why understanding this code is necessary to solve it).
- Most importantly, the title needs to reflect the actual problem you have. "I don't understand this code." Is not a problem that is useful to anyone else (because of the title -- no one ever searches "I don't understand this code.").  What could be useful is : "Scaling to 1M network requests with Python Library X".

Overall, it's up to you to make your question on topic.  It may seem unfair that we don't just accept all the ["Why doesn't this code work?"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20why%20doesn%27t%20this%20code%20work) Questions or the ["I don't understand this code"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com%20I%20don%27t%20understand%20this%20code) questions, but if you look at the ones we've let through, it's clear they aren't useful to anyone else if they don't follow these criteria.

Answer (score 13):

On Stackoverflow it is absolutely irrelevant (putting aside legal questions and the like...) where you got your code/question/problem from. It is the **question** itself that matters.

We already have [tons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874816/what-does-this-do) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028720/lambda-expression-what-does-this-do) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206450/what-does-this-do) [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442916/what-is-this-javascript-operator) "what does this do", "what does this mean", what kind of operator is this" or others. [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683720/what-is-this-operator-1). [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941330/c-programming-xor-bitwise-operation).

Some of them are really good, some of them are bad. But none stand or fall with the fact that they were found in open-source code. It is important to phrase the question correctly and to boil it down to a single problem.

I have seen some questions here on SO by people that have to deal with code from colleagues. Sometimes they just dump the whole program/function. Your instinct will already tell you that that's a **bad question**.

Others will find a specific operator they have never seen and ask about it. Your instinct will already tell you that that's a **good question** (mostly)

The problem with your question(s) currently seems to be that they are too broad. If you really intend on asking questions about how code is *organized* you better make really sure that you find a **specific problem** in this organization, maybe the relation between two classes that employ a pattern you have never seen. Hierarchy, responsibilities and code structure might be questions of taste/opinion and you fare better avoiding such questions on SO.

So I don't think we/you need a special tag. Just tag the language of the code and make it a good and interesting question about the thing that you need help with. **Yes please! Ask for help in "source-diving", but do it the SO-way**

Comment: As evidence of this, consider a question about XML Serialization in .NET which is part of the core framework, versus C++ where the 3rd party library LibXML2 is often used. It would be unfair to disallow LibXML2 questions while allowing .NET XML questions, simply because one is an OS/3rd party lib versus the other being part of the core framework.

Answer (score 1):

A question that was strictly about the organisational structure to use for e.g. a Python package, or why a particular open-source project doesn't seem to follow the directory name conventions that you expect could be on-topic. If you can summarise the structure under question, as opposed to link the external project, then I think all would be good.

Your question goes beyond how "source is organised" into categorisation of the code into chunks to help learn it. This is both:

- Too broad - as you say, it is a lot of code to read and understand.
- Too subjective - the categorisation you are looking can be approached in many different ways.

Your options for getting assistance I think are also quite open:

1. Contact the project owners, or search for a group that has made a NumPy-compatible project, to see if they have any resources or pointers that could help you.
2. Start your project with limited understanding, and ask on Stack Overflow when faced with a more direct/practical issue. As you won't know yet what structures will work best in your project, you need to be willing to re-factor heavily (as an aside, this is the approach I have taken with the much simpler, but similarly-focused Ruby library NArray, and I now use its C library in my personal projects).
3. Ask for help approaching your problem in a general sense e.g. "How can I organise my approach to studying the internals of a large open-source project?" on a site that could offer you some general guidance. Although unfortunately *not* on-topic for Programmers SE, it does look like this question has been asked before. The question there is locked, but answers may include some useful advice for you, and prevent you needing to ask the same question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6395/how-do-you-dive-into-large-code-bases

Comment: "how can I approach learning blah blah..." is unlikely to fly at Programmers. Education advice has a dedicated close reason over there. See this [meta guidance](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980) for more details. See also: [Where to start](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)

Comment: @gnat: I'm not sure the answer you linked addresses the OP's question, yours is more about career and education questions. The OP's question is about tackling the understanding of a large piece of code. I will re-phrase my advice, and have found a counter-example to yours: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6395/how-do-you-dive-into-large-code-bases

Comment: have you read the mod notice over there? "This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed." (is has got [meta-tag:historical-lock] few months ago)

Comment: No, missed that (I just saw the up-votes) will adjust my answer, thanks.