# Let's clean up [open-source]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, clean-up

We've decided that questions about [how open source projects are organized](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284515/359284) are usually not on-topic. You might even say that it's difficult for questions about open source to be *on-topic at all* based on the answer there.

There are [3,683 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source) on Stack Overflow tagged [open-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source). Of those, [2,717 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bopen-source%5D+closed%3Ayes) are closed, [966 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bopen-source%5d%20closed%3ano) are open. So roughly 74% of all questions asked in [open-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source) have been closed.

It looks like cleaning it up is going to mean **burninating the tag completely**. With the serious quality issues in the tag, I think this is our best option.

---

This tag was recently cleaned up as part of "[This tag should not be [legal]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295117/359284)", and now the clearly off-topic questions have been closed and/or removed. There are still [some well-received, open questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bopen-source%5d%20closed%3ano) that are better off with a historical lock or being migrated to [Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (if possible).

The rest of the questions can live without the [open-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source) tag. I think at this point, the tag can safely be removed from Stack Overflow.

[Open Source SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) was recently launched, though it's way too early to start directing questions to it.

Comment: There's an [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com) site :D

Comment: I wish I could place a bounty on this, because the tag is still a mess a year later.

Comment: @BilltheLizard not to speak of six years later.

Answer (score 14):

Since questions coming out of that tag are likely to be off-topic, it would probably be a good idea to go through it and migrate/close/delete off-topic questions to set an example for what's actually allowed in it on Stack Overflow.

> Should we just close all of the off-topic questions?

Yes; that would probably be a good place to start.

> Should we burninate the tag as well?

I'm inclined to say yes, because I don't think any particularly great on-topic questions will come out of it. If the question can't stand on its own without the tag, it probably shouldn't be there.

> Should we start tossing around historical locks for some of the higher voted ones?

I think a lot of the common questions can be migrated to Programmers, but for the ones that were particularly well-received, a historical lock would probably be a good idea to demonstrate *here* what kind of questions shouldn't be asked and to preserve the reputation gained for those who put a lot of work into that particular question or its answers.

> Should we just look away and pretend nothing is wrong in [open-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source)?

[image: Never!]

Comment: Before trying to flag a bunch of them for migration to Programmers, you might want to either stop by the Programmer's chat room (whiteboard) or post on the P.SE meta there asking for feedback on specific questions that are candidate to move. About 1:4 of the questions that are currently migrated from SO to P.SE get rejected (and those are all done by moderators) - the last thing anyone wishes is another 20 questions to show up on the front page of P.SE and have them get closed (note: P.SE gets about 50 questions/day).

Comment: @MichaelT I wasn't suggesting migration for the majority of them; by "common questions" I meant those that wouldn't be closed on P.SE but that didn't have specific historical significance on SO. Thanks for the warning, though.

Comment: Remember also that [questions older than 60 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days) can't be migrated except by SE devs and community managers.  [Its happened in the past](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6861/) (looking at the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/706799/revisions) I wonder what was being drunk at the time and if people would share...). Note that the quality of those would have to be astounding and on topic on P.SE.

Comment: Historical post locks are also useful for providing guidance for problems that are commonly encountered even if they aren't necessarily on point in the SO community. That point cannot be overlooked.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot going on here. But I want to focus on two things. The first, is whether to burninate the tag.

For that I say yes. A lot of questions with the `open-source` tag don't belong on SO. If you're asking about a tool or software package that is open-source, it should be sufficient to use that name. Open-source is a development model and SO really isn't the right forum to talk about that. In that respect, Programmers SE is a better place. But, I think a blanket migration to Programmers SE is a bad move.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700/arguments-for-going-open-source) looks like a good migration candidate.

The second, is what to do with all the posts tagged with `open-source`? To that end I propose that we implement a test and come to a determination of whether or not we should hold on to these posts. This is case by case, and it may take a while to get rid of all these posts, but for the sake of keeping the SO site clean, it's probably worth it. Here's how I envision this test to work.

First, ask: Is this question about a specific open source project or framework generally? If yes, then the question is *not* grist for SO. This question would eliminate the following immediately:

- [With .NET open sourcing is a MS runtime avaliable on Linux and Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072240/with-net-open-sourcing-is-a-ms-runtime-avaliable-on-linux-and-mac)
- [Is Mono ready for prime time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450/is-mono-ready-for-prime-time)
- [Is Google chrome open source available for development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886100/is-google-chrome-open-source-available-for-development)

In fact, these questions seem to all be about the relative status of certain open-source projects. SO is definitely not the site to address this concern, but I'm wondering: if this is pain point for developers, why not solve it?

Second, ask: is this about the open-source community? How to contribute, etc. If so, then it's also *not* grist for SO. This would get rid of:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656794/open-source-contribution-at-work
- [How/where to start reading open source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318684/how-where-to-start-reading-open-source-code)

At this point we come to an interesting crossroad. 
Namely, **how do we determine whether a post that has failed these tests, be preserved for the sake of history?**

I did a little digging in addition to OP's comment. I looked at the top 30 posts with the `open-source` tag (which, incidentally, also constitute the questions with over 50 upvotes).

> 29% of all questions asked are closed - That's never a good sign

Of those only **8** were still open. Even in the crème de la crème of posts, almost **75%** of questions are closed. I think tossing out historical post protection is the right idea. But I'm inclined to say that if it passes the above two tests, the post should be canned *unless* it has over a certain number of views or votes. I'm not sure where the threshold should be set.

Comment: [That good post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573768/sentiment-analysis-for-twitter-in-python) is actually a recommendation request which we're [actively closing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/282932/clean-up-looking-for-something-questions). [open-source] is one of those tags that was identified as a bad tag through the closing work. Maybe you can find a better question which should be preseved.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Hmm. Good point. And perhaps even a stronger justification for closing any posts that pass this test.