# Tag [crowdsourcing] is broad, undescribed and should be burninated

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I've noticed this strange [crowdsourcing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crowdsourcing) tag and wasn't really sure about its meaning in the context of Stack Overflow. I googled a little, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowdsourcing) says:

> Crowdsourcing is a sourcing model in which individuals or organizations obtain goods or services including ideas, voting, micro-tasks, and finances from a large, relatively open, and often rapidly evolving group of participants. As of 2021, crowdsourcing typically involves using the internet to attract and divide work between participants to achieve a cumulative result, however it may not always be an online activity.

Basically, it is a model/process of work distribution in the real world. This word/tag is similar in category to words like *freelancer*, *outsourcing*, *company*, etc. I'm not seeing any related categories as tags, so I'm a little confused if this represents the right thing.

Is this tag reasonable? What group of questions should it represent and what category should this tag cover?

This might be also a good starting point for adding a description to this tag or removing it completely.

---

Note there are several crowdfunding platforms/frameworks and they have their own tags:

- [crowdflower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crowdflower)
- [pybossa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pybossa)
- [toloka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toloka)

In context of categorization, I imagine that [crowdsourcing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crowdsourcing) is comparable to [versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versioning), and each of the versioning systems ([git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git), [subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subversion), [perforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perforce), etc.) represents a piece of actual crowdsourcing's framework/platform ([crowdflower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crowdflower), [pybossa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pybossa), [toloka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toloka), etc.).

---

**EDIT:** to start burnination, I'm adding proper tag + answers to the related questions.

---

[crowdsourcing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crowdsourcing) currently has 67 questions, 5 of them are only with this tag (see below).

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   - No, it doesn't clearly describe the content. It can either represent:

     - a process/model of how the code is created
     - a group of people that contributes to the solution
     - the software used for this activity
     - data obtained from a crowd-source
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   - No, it is not clear what it represents (see #1). The tag has existed for over decade, yet nobody wrote a description for it. It is unclear what category it should account for, except for being a meta-tag for "category of contribution".
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   - Usually this tag comes with an additional tag representing "crowdsourcing software", like [crowdflower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crowdflower), [pybossa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pybossa), [toloka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toloka). Due to this, [crowdsourcing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crowdsourcing) represents only duplicate information with no additional context to the question.
   - There are exactly 5 questions, that have only this tag and no other:

     - [What crowdsourcing platforms are the most effective?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879423/what-crowdsourcing-platforms-are-the-most-effective)
     - [How to ensure correctness of data gathered via crowdsourcing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785246/how-to-ensure-correctness-of-data-gathered-via-crowdsourcing)
     - [Increase quality of crowd-sourced info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255871/increase-quality-of-crowd-sourced-info)
     - [How do I redirect Crowdflower users to my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974332/how-do-i-redirect-crowdflower-users-to-my-website)
     - [Is there anyone worked or currently working on Crowdsourcing and has used Gmission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68545282/is-there-anyone-worked-or-currently-working-on-crowdsourcing-and-has-used-gmissi)
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   - I guess, yes. Yet it is too general and abstract idea.

Comment: Based on its currently visible questions, looks like [this tag has existed since 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/164831/1).

Comment: Seems like a candidate for burnination to me. The concept it describes is not, in itself, on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: In favor of burning the heck out of it too. It does not add anything useful to the questions it is on. The tag itself is relatively harmless, but the questions it is applied to need some culling: they are largely off-topic to begin with.

Comment: Forcing [crowdsourcing] down the drain

Comment: Let's croudsource this burnination

Comment: Isn't *every* question on StackOverflow an effort to crowdsource programming, if you look at it a certain way?

Answer (score 17):

**On topicality**

Let us review the list of *on-topic* cases from the help center:

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- software tools commonly used by programmers
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Crowdsourcing is not a *programming problem*. Sure, it is *related* to programming, but only insofar as *programmers* participate in projects that use the crowdsourcing model. Some programmers are believers — it does not make theological questions on-topic here; we all eat — it does not make apple pie recipes any more on-topic here; the list can go on forever, but I hope the point is clear enough.

Crowdsourcing is definitely not a *software algorithm*, at least I am not aware of one. An algorithm can deal with a problem related to crowdsourcing, which would make a question about it on-topic due to it being an [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) with the core issue related to programming (memory management issues, time/space complexity, implementing relational graphs, etc.).

Crowdsourcing is certainly not a *tool*, it is a model. I hope this claim is self-evident enough to not require further elaboration.

Crowdsourcing is a *practical* (it is a practice, after all) and *answerable* (for example, legal considerations of the model) problem, but it is not *unique to software development*. It is just a model, it works the same way in art, linguistics, and [even ornithology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowdsourcing#In_ornithology).

**On meta-tagginess**

On top of being inherently off-topic, it is also a clear-cut case of a meta-tag. It does not describe what a question is about, it describes its *context* (the following is not a list of examples on-topic on Stack Overflow): legal concerns *when* crowdsourcing, meaning of ownership *when* crowdsourcing, resolving collaborator disputes *when* crowdsourcing.

**On burnination**

Given the above, it is a prime candidate for [burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag). However, please follow the [proper procedure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) given there currently are more than 50 questions tagged with it (no, editing it out from 18 questions does not count) by making a burnination request. It should be an easy consensus given all the above.

**On specific tags**

The individual tags you listed, however, represent practical programming problems with the technologies involved: using the Crowdflower Markup Language, issues with the [API client](https://github.com/cloudyr/crowdflower), etc. Those tags are *on-topic* and should not be touched.

Comment: The same as with [the open-source tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284976/2711488) which for some inexplicable reason still exist…

Comment: @Holger not enough active users noticing, I suppose? Might also be the sheer scope of the effort...

Comment: @OlegValter nah, most of these should be tackled by SE, rather than individual users, since most of the questions are correctly tagged, yet have the very unfortunate tag.

Comment: It's not a problem of users not noticing, it's a problem of users noticing but not caring because tag curation is horribly asymmetrical. It's incredibly easy to create a tag on SO, but incredibly difficult to get rid of one because the burnination policy is purposefully designed to make doing so as difficult and painful as possible... and then people just go and re-create that tag anyway. Essentially it's a war where the only way to win is to not play, especially since SE Inc. resolutely refuses to introduce tools to make curation easier.

Comment: @IanKemp [hear hear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402384/792066).

Comment: Yes, it's actually a giant conspiracy that actions which are *destructive* have more safeguards surrounding them than actions which merely involve creating things.

Comment: @CodyGray that's a fallacy. You should know better than anyone that **nothing is really destroyed on the site.** There are records of everything. If I remove a tag from a question, anyone can go to the post history and revert that (it happened already). So, calling burnination a process that can't be reverted is like calling closing a process that can't be reverted.

Comment: I have no issues with safeguards, I have issues with wholly unnecessary barriers. Not to mention that any critique of the burnination process as it stands and/or suggestions to modify it, are shut down faster than you can say "it was inscribed on stone tablets by our lord and saviour Shog9 so it's therefore perfect and may never be changed".

Comment: Tag removals are *extremely difficult* to revert. I've personally spent *hours* reverting an incorrect tag removal. That is time that could be better spent. Speaking of fallacies, agreeing with someone's logic is not the same as pretending their words are infallible.

Comment: @CodyGray then ask for the tools that allows you to do it! It makes everyone happy instead of at least one of the two very unhappy. The only reason why reverting it is difficult is because you don't have tools that make it easy. BTW, reverting tag removals is as difficult as removing tags. Both actions require manually going to every question and editing the question.

Comment: @IanKemp the funny thing is that even then Shog words were altered. The original test was that it should pass every assessment, but SO got that it should fail every assessment.

Comment: _"does not make apple pie recipes any more on-topic here"_ — but questions on [raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi)e can definitely be on topic

Comment: "However, please follow the proper procedure..."   Which means nobody can touch this tag until a community burnination effort. And at the pace these are going, that will probably never happen.  So now we're stuck with the tag for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @DanielWiddis probably, but it does not justify tag vigilantism :) There is not much work to be done, only 59 questions - if we cannot muster enough strength to work through this set of questions, maybe we did not need it to be burned in the first place. I just went through 6 posts to bring it to 59 posts VTC'ing and editing posts.

Comment: @OlegValter Well if you subtract the closed questions [there are only 48 open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcrowdsourcing%5D+closed%3Ano+is%3Aquestion&searchOn=3)...